# Does quoting of identifiers improve security?

Tags: sql, security

I know that in `MySQL` we can quote identifiers with back tick symbol, whereas in `Oracle` (and other RDBMS that follow standard) we can use double quotes around table names and field names. I wonder whether it somehow improves security and should we use this technique in real world applications in parallel with traditional methods like preparation of sql statements?

Comment: quoting identifiers has nothing to with with sql injection or security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder whether it somehow improves security

If you're accepting user input for column or table names and putting them into a query then yes, you will need to correctly encode them to avoid SQL injection. Specifically, wrap them in double-quotes, and replace any double-quote character in the name with a doubled-double-quote. (In MySQL, backtick and doubled-backtick, or set the `ANSI_QUOTES` config to make it use the standard double quote.)

It's really unusual to be accepting arbitrary schema names from user input though, and rarely a good idea. Typically where you allow particular columns to be identified (eg for a `sort=something` parameter) it's better to permit only a whitelist of known-good columns.

When you are only writing fixed queries there is no particular security need to quote schema names, although it's probably a good idea to ensure that your queries still work reliably in the face of different DBMSs with different reserved words.